# NestJS: DI and class inheritance

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I am running into issues getting the proper class injected with NestJS. There is a base class `@Injectable() export class FakeBinanceClient implements ITradeClient {...` and a child class `@Injectable() export class ScheduledFakeBinanceClient extends FakeBinanceClient {...`

I do inject the child explicitely in another class by `constructor(@Inject(ScheduledFakeBinanceClient) tradeClient: ITradeClient, ...`. However, the `FakeBinanceClient` base class gets injected.

The main module also states clearly to use the child class:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [ScheduledFakeBinanceClient, ... (no FakeBinanceClient)]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any idea whe the child class isn't being injected?

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't a code problem. I simply had to delete the dist-folder and rebuild.